# How to convert this fix this ASP.NET MVC5 route?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I'm not sure how to convert this AttributeRoute into an MVC5 route.

```
[GET("", IsAbsoluteUrl = true)] // => main home page.
[GET("Index")]
public ActionResult Index(..) { .. }
```

The `IsAbsoluteUrl` is one of the things that is confusing me.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the notes found here: http://attributerouting.net/#route-prefixes the `IsAbsoluteUrl` flag is designed to ignore the `RoutePrefix` defined on the Controller. For example:

```
[RoutePrefix("MyApp")]
public class MyController : Controller {

    [GET("", IsAbsoluteUrl = true)] //1
    [GET("Index")] //2
    public ActionResult Index() {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, using the 'standard' AttributeRouting (for lack of a better name), the following routes should map to your Index() method:

- / (1)
- /MyApp/Index (2)

The new Attribute based routing in MVC5 has similar functionality (being based on the former), just slightly different syntax (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx)

```
[RoutePrefix("MyApp")]
public class MyController : Controller {

    [Route("~/")] //1
    [Route("Index")] //2
    public ActionResult Index() {
        ...
    }
}
```

The tilde `~` seems to be equivalent of `IsAbsoluteUrl`.